# how to make a 2-d Array of labels using C#

Tags: c#, textbox, simulator, label

I am working on a project to implement a simulator software of a certain microprocessor.

I need to implement something that displays the memory content of the microprocessor and changes hapeens in it as a 2-d array of bytes. something that is similar to the memory window illustrated in the following image (the image is taken from Keil uVision simulator)

http://www.keil.com/uvision/images/db_view_memory1.png

I have decided to implement it using an array of labels or a a large text box filled with 2-d array of bytes.
but I see that it is not a practical solution at all.

what do you suggest? what is the best and practical solution from your point of view?

the second question is, in the above image, if we put the mouse cursor on a certain byte, its address is displayed in a bubble, note or so. I have no idea how to implement this using C#, please recommend me any tutorials or articles.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use DataGridView the cell index is the same Array Index but u have to hide the columns and rows lines and make multi cell selectable. or a Richtextbox with toolTip.

Comment: nice sloution too!

but don't you think that this view is less suitable for memory content?